# Is there a high-level Ag-Grid event to listen to any change to column state?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I use Ag-Grid together with Angular and I would like to listen to **any** event that modify column state.

As of now, I have to list all events:

- `(columnVisible)=onCol($event)`
- `(columnMoved)=onCol($event)`
- etc.

Is there a generic or higher-level event I could rely on in order to listen to any change to column state?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's `addGlobalListener`, listed [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/).

There's an example: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-api-example

Here's the relevant code from the Angular version of the example:

```js
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

    params.api.addGlobalListener(function(type, event) {
        if (type.indexOf("column") >= 0) {
            console.log("Got column event: ", event);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know how call I call a angular method inside the function? In that example if I change the console.log for saveState () I got an "Uncaught ReferenceError: saveState is not defined"

Comment: @JMarques - change the function to a fat-arrow function, e.g. `params.api.addGlobalListener( (type, event) => { this.saveState() });`

Answer (score 0):

```
const gridId = 'myGrid1';

const gridOptions = {
  onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    gridOptions.columnApi.applyColumnState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(gridId)));     // restore
    params.api.addGlobalListener((type, event) => {
      localStorage.setItem(gridId,JSON.stringify(gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState()));   // save
    });
  }
}
```