# AgGrid Detect changing on columns/filters/sortings events

Tags: state, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid and I'd like to save the layout/state of the user. Pretty much something [like this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#saving-and-restoring-column-state)

This solution forces the user to click on the button to save the preferences ("Save state"). There is some other way/event to detect that the user changed the state of the table (in order, to me to save and avoid to force the user to click on a button for that)?

I was hopping to find some method [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/) but i didn't..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54823776/is-there-a-high-level-ag-grid-event-to-listen-to-any-change-to-column-state).

All the events are [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/) but i prefer to add a global event:

*addGlobalListener(listener)*   Add an event listener for all event types coming from the grid.) 
Source: [AgGrid javascript grid api](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/)

Answer (score 1):

I initially had code that listened to all of the applicable events from the grid, but ultimately, I found it easier to just save the entire grid state in the component's onDestroy method, regardless of whether anything has actually changed.